# delete calender invitation using ics file in php

Tags: php

I want to delete(cancel) the calender event using ics file. But when i create a ics file to delete the event my outllok shows the alert saying "The ICS attachment can't be viewed beacuse it contains an item that is not calender related".

My ics file is -

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20190211T092800Z
UID:f4efcbecf5fbe46d344cc6d494902ed6
DTSTAMP:1549909455
LOCATION:gurgaon
DESCRIPTION:simple
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CANCELLED
URL;VALUE=URI:mydomain.com/events/
SUMMARY:simple
DTSTART:20190211T062800Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Please help me in this issue

Comment: How are you modifying the file?  Where's your PHP code?

Comment: I am asking whats wrong with this ics file why it cant delete the event